# Como reversar transaciones en Laravel DB::beginTransaction()

Tags: laravel, transacciones

En una inserción en varias tablas, uso el DB::beginTransaction(), la primera tabla en la cual inserto necesito el ID con el cual se guarda el registro para usarlo en las otras tablas que están relacionadas con la primera.
/* Inserto la O.T.*/

```
                    DB::beginTransaction();
        // asegurar que las transacciones se guarden correctamente
        try {
            /* Inserto la O.T.*/
            $ordenTrabajo = new OrdenTrabajo();
            $ordenTrabajo->fechaRecepcion = $request->fechaRecepcion;
            $ordenTrabajo->numeroGuiaIngreso = $request->guiaRetiro;
            $ordenTrabajo->numeroGuiaDespacho = $request->guiaDespacho;           
            $ordenTrabajo->fechaAprobacion = $request->fechaAprobacion;       
            $ordenTrabajo->sede_id   = $request->sede_id ;                       
            
            $ordenTrabajo->numeroFactura = $request->numeroFactura;    
            $ordenTrabajo->orden_compra_id  = $request->ordenCompra ;    
            $ordenTrabajo->lugarServicio = $request->lugarServicio;    
            $ordenTrabajo->vehiculo_id  = $request->vehiculo_id ;    
            $ordenTrabajo->numeroCotizacion = $request->numeroCotizacion;    

            $ordenTrabajo->fechaEntrega = $request->fechaEntrega;
            $ordenTrabajo->user_id  = $request->tecnico_id[0];
            $ordenTrabajo->encargado_id = $request->encargado_id;
            $ordenTrabajo->jefeArea_id = $request->jefeArea_id;
            $ordenTrabajo->controlCalidad_id = $request->controlCalidad_id;
            $ordenTrabajo->status='0';
            $ordenTrabajo->save();
```

El problema se me presenta cuando hay algún error en la inserción de las otras tablas, el ROLLBACK funciona (elimina la orden insertada), pero el consecutivo de la primera tabla se incrementa internamente, o sea que si hago de nuevo el INSERT y todo va bien, el ID de las Ordenes se me salta y necesito que el ID mantenga el consecutivo.

```
DB::commit();
                return back()->with('success','Orden registrada  Exitosamente...');
            }catch (\Exception $e) {            
                DB::rollBack();                
                return back()->withInput()->with('success','Error en la creación de la Orden de Trabajo...');
            }
```

Comment: La idea de las columnas tipo IDENTITY es que no tengan un "significado", por lo cual no deberías usarlo como clave de relación con otras tablas. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Y como quedan las reglas de Laravel, donde el campo relación debe llevar el nombre de la tabla mas el id ejemplo OrdenTrabajo_id?

Comment: Pues eso. Una cosa es la regla y otra la forma en que SQL funciona. No eres el primero con este problema. Lo usual en estos casos es llevar una tabla adicional con los registros de secuencia que necesitas, de esta forma si haces `rollback`, el registro de secuencia también es actualizado.

Comment: Cuando tenga tiempo, si nadie antes te ha dado una respuesta, intentaré responderte.

Comment: gracias Mauricio, pues soy nuevo con este framework y lo que leí lo interprete mal, anteriormente con Php lo hacia de esa manera llevaba mi tabla de referencias aparte. Lo tendré en cuenta para mis próximas tablas, Estaré atento a tu respuesta.

Comment: Por qué necesitás que el ID quede correlativo? No debería importar.

Comment: Azeós, lo necesito para llevar el correlativo de las ordenes de trabajo q se realizan, debería haber creado un campo numero_orden como lo mencionó Mauricio, pero lo hice así por lo de las relaciones en laravel, pague la novatada.